# Antd Custom Radio Button Mega Option Form Component

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd, custom-component

Using Antd + React.js, I am looking to create the following large "mega option" selector in place of the traditional Radio.Button experience.

I am currently able to lay these out as Card components with the `hoverable` option turned on (to add box shadow to the card when hovered). I would like to link these "Cards" as Radio Options such that they are accessible in my Form state just like a regular Radio.Button option.

**Current "Card-like" Design:** Final output should retain the style function just like a regular radio option.

[image]

```js
<Form form={form} layout="vertical" name="add-form">
    <Form.Item
        name="type"
        label="Please select a type below:"
        rules={[
            {
                required: true,
                message: 'Please select your type',
            },
        ]}
    >
        <Row gutter={16}>
            <Col md={12}>
                <Card
                    hoverable
                    title="Radio Button 1"
                    extra={<CheckCircleFilled style={{ color: '#12cc55' }} />}
                >
        This is a short description of the radio button.
                </Card>
            </Col>
            <Col md={12}>
                <Card
                    hoverable
                    title="Radio Button 2"
                >
        This is a short description of the radio button.
                </Card>
            </Col>
        </Row>
    </Form.Item>
</Form>
```

I would really appreciate someone with a little more Antd custom component experience taking a look at this and showing how this can be converted to a radio option.

All resources I have seen so far are not Antd specific or don't show how it can be used with Antd forms. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

you can do it easily.. use card component inside radio component. style the card component as you wish. 
check this example..... https://codesandbox.io/s/heuristic-mendeleev-pjcvg

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I am aware of the ability to customise the content of the radio button, what I'm looking for is a custom radio component (ie. with hidden radio button and instead, the whole card becomes one big radio button. Similar to [this](https://codepen.io/dromo77/pen/ZEQWyaZ) but based on Antd

Comment: you can have your preferred custom component by doing some styling.  
I have done some test styling ... check on `styles.css` file. https://codesandbox.io/s/interesting-goodall-qszw6